# Vuex module decorator : how to call mutation from component

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex-module-decorators

I have this `store`

**store/r2o.ts**

```
import { Module, VuexModule, Mutation } from 'vuex-module-decorators'
import { IR2O } from '~/models/R2O'

@Module({
  name: 'r2o',
  namespaced: true
})
export default class R2O extends VuexModule {
  r2os: Array<IR2O> = []
  @Mutation
  set(p: Array<IR2O>) {
    this.r2os = p
  }
}
```

I need to call this `mutation` in my **component**
how can i do it ??

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it directly

```
this.$store.commit('r2o/set', [])
```

If you want to use vuex-class

```
import { namespace } from 'vuex-class'

...


@namespace('r2o').Mutation('set') setR2o: (p: Array<IR20>) => any


myMethod() {
  this.setR2o([])
}
```